# Problem with structuremap creating linqtosql datacontext in ASP.NET from background process

Tags: asp.net-mvc, structuremap

I have an ASP.NET MVC application with LinqToSql. The datalayer contains methods for performing crud operations on the database. Each method can request a datacontext from structuremap, which is configured to return the same datacontext per http request (InstanceScope.Hybrid), so I can call several methods on the datalayer, and in the end, submitchanges is called, so all crud operations are contained in one transaction. So far, this is working fine. 
I also have workflow activities (using WF4), which of course run in a separate thread, the workflow thread.Some activities also perform crud operations using the same datalayer. The problem is, that structuremap (sometimes) returns the same datacontext for different activities, probably because these activities run on the same workflow thread. This is causing problems, because the datacontext may cache instances of entities, which have been changed between the execution two activities (because data was changed from the web application).

Eg.

Activity1

- calls method A on datalayer => method A requests datacontext from structuremap => datacontext X1 is returned
- calls method B on datalayer => method B requests datacontext from structuremap =>
  datacontext X1 is returned
- calls submitchanges, A and B are committed

Web application

- calls method B on datalayer=> method B requests datacontext from structuremap => datacontext X2 is returned
- calls submitchanges, B is commited

Activity 2

- calls method B on datalayer => method B request datacontext from structuremap => datacontext X1 is returned (=> here I would need another datacontext).

Datacontext X1 is caching entity instances, web application has changed entity in between, so I get changeconflict exception

From the webapplication, structuremap instancescope hybrid is ok, because each web request will give me another datacontext instance, from WF this is not ok... I can not configure structuremap in WF to return instance per request, because that would give me different datacontexts in method A and method B... so A and B would not be contained in one transaction.

Maybe if I could tell structuremap to dispose the datacontext, whenever submitchanges is called, this would solve my problem, but I don't know if or how this can be done with structuremap.

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you want EjectAllInstances method; that will get rid of the cached instance of the data context, so the next time you request one from StructureMap it will be created fresh.

Comment: Isn't this dangerous to do? There may be other background processes having another instance of datacontext, they will get ejected too...

Comment: Yeah, it will call dispose, so that won't work.  I think what you really need is a custom scope that hooks into WF somehow, so SM can be aware of when to dispose the cached instance.